How to fix failed to create symbolic link: File exists
so i was trying to install fabric for minecraft but it said
`ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/yj/.minecraft/.minecraft': File exists'
how do i fix this error? i have searched for this error but couldn't fix it help pz

You might have to try to find the source of which you tried to create the link and redo everything.

follow these steps , maybe it will help

Identify the Existing Link
Remove the Existing Link or File
Recreate the Symbolic Link Manually (Optional)
check permission , and try to install again .

